# how to compile postresql from source and install it to an isolated location?

Tags: c, postgresql, makefile

I'm trying to perform some tests on postgres code where I need to iteratively compile code, run parts of it, over and over.

For that reason, I don't want to do a 'make install,' since cleaning that up will be a pain. I'd like to install all relevant files under a single direcory, say /tmp/pgsql_test1.

I see that `make check` does a `make -C . DESTDIR='/whatever'`

However, as far as I can tell, this isn't documented in pgsql's docs. I'm also not a c/c++ developer so I don't know if this is a standard stuff. The `-C` flag seems to imply that only client libraries are being installed. I'd like to execute pgsql under normal usage, including the part which listens over the network, parses sql, etc.

Comment: You need to have it installed if you want to be able to run it.

Comment: The `-C` flag to make has it change directories before executing. `-C .` is effectively a no-op. Using a targeted installation directory is perfectly standard if the build system supports it.

Comment: What do you mean with *an isolated location*? Do you mean a `chroot`ed environment? a `jail`ed environment? a isolated from network environment? Please, edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control where postgres installs to using the `configure` script. This is true of just about any software that uses autotools (which is what made that `configure` script).

You can always take a look at the configure options by running `./configure --help`. In this case, these are the relevant options:

```
masheen(~/postgres-src) > ./configure --help

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local/pgsql]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

...

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/postgresql]
```

If you specify `--prefix`, it'll override `--exec-prefix`, and both of those drive most of the parts installation locations.

```
masheen(~/postgres-src) > ./configure --prefix=/tmp/pgsql_tmp1
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I saw the prefix flag but its description made me pause: "Install all files under the directory PREFIX instead of /usr/local/pgsql. *****The actual files will be installed into various subdirectories; no files will ever be installed directly into the PREFIX directory.*****" What's this about files not being directly installed into PREFIX dir?

Comment: I'll use FreeBSD as an example - `/usr/local` is the typical prefix that all third party gets installed to. Binaries used by normal users go into `/usr/local/bin`. "System" and "administrator" binaries go in `/usr/local/sbin`. Config files go into `/usr/local/etc`. So on, and so forth for include files, man pages, shared libraries, shared files. Every file has its place somewhere in the filesystem. Programs are not typically installed into their own self-contained directory. Thus, whatever you set `PREFIX` to will usually have nothing but more folders (bin, sbin, etc, lib).

Comment: Please one that after compiling & installing in a "non standard" directory, there is still some manual tweaking required to add the binaries to the PATH and to add the libdir to the list of locations used by the loader.